# jQuery Smooth Horizontal Scroll

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling, jquery-easing

I've created a long horizontal page and using anchors to navigate to section's within the page. I added a jQuery smooth scrolling function but it's not taking affect?

Here's the navigation:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#starters">Starters</a></li>
<li><a href="#main">Main Dishes</a></li>
<li><a href="#special">Special Dishes</a></li>
<li><a href="#side">Side Dishes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Within the content i've added corresponding anchors:

```
<a name="starters"></a>
```

And here's the jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
$('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
    }, 1500, "easeInOutExpo");
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

The anchor's work fine, clicking the navigation takes you to the desired section but it *jumps* instead of scrolling.

Any ideas why??

Answer (score 2):

It's simple add class to your `div` which need to scroll for example below:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="a"><a href="#starters">Starters</a></li>
<li class="b"><a href="#main">Main Dishes</a></li>
<li class="c"><a href="#special">Special Dishes</a></li>
<li class="d"><a href="#side">Side Dishes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, your js will be like this:

```
$(function() {
$('#clickable element').bind('click',function(event){
    $('#targetelement or div').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $('.a').offset().left
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

likewise you can build js for b,c,d classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct except for this:

```
<a name="starters"></a>
```

Change `name` to `id`. There is no HTML `name` attribute for anchor tags as far as I know. Also, you don't need "corresponding anchors" for your sections. Assuming your sections are wrapped with a `<section>` or `<div>`, just give each of your wrapping block elements an `id` identical to the `href` from each of your anchor links. So:

`<section id="starters">content</section>`

Comment: This is true for HTML5, however <a>'s do have names otherwise: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to use jquery easing for animations
http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kleopatra. I have the same problem than Rumman and the solution was use the jquery easing library for enable the animation